# ASP.NET MVC 4: different customers, differents views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, architecture

I am pretty new to MVC4 although the basic concepts are clear. At the moment I am planning a larger project where there is one requirement: depending on the customer I have to show different UI/views for the same process.
Let's say there are customers A and B; both create appointments, but the data entered by customer A are slightly different than that from customer B. So the UI for customer A looks different than customers B's UI for managing appointments. I can identify customer A and B (or their customers) by the login-ID. Another requirement is to flexibly add more views for possible customers C, D, ... All should be in one solution, no branching etc.
What is the best approach for this in MVC4? What architecture should I use? Any ideas and examples?

Thanks in advance!

Heiko

Answer (score 3):

To resolve your question generally, I suggest you should take look the term multi-tenant. Each user/customer will have scheme specifics theme, UI. One of framework asp.MVC can adapt multi-tenant is Orchard. You can look at it at [here](https://orchard.codeplex.com/).

Or you can get tutorial step by step to implement a simple multi-tenant at [here](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Simple-approach-to-multi-tenancy-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot, "multi-tenant" was exactly the thing that I was looking for! Found a lot of tutorials, MS p&p even has a 200+ pages about this matter, look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966499.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Its a different way to implement this.

Specify view in action.

Create custom action filter.

Extend the default ViewEngine.

look [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx)

or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176703/changing-the-view-in-an-asp-net-mvc-filter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial views to put common functionalists and design different layout page  and views for suitable for customers. Yes, it will be in one solution only.

About architecture..In your question you described the problem only related to design views, but the overall architectural design depend upon several factors of the application and the context. I hope we can help better if you provide more detail about the scenario you are facing. Thanks.